LED identification
Please help identify the LED by photo and description. SMD, size 3x3 mm, silicone lens, white above 5000 K, 200 mA at 2.8 V. It looks like OSRAM OSLON SSL 80, but the volt-ampere characteristics of these doides don't match, ~240 mA at 2.8 V. 
Photos: 


 
full size photo 1 
full size photo 2 
full size photo 3
